# Create a jar file from command promt like eclipse export

Tags: eclipse, shell, command-line, jar

I have to make a jar from a shell something like this:
[image]

and the jar must look like this:

[image]

and if I try this from a command promt, with something like this:
jar cvfe xmlvalidator.jar * src/*.class

executed from XMLValidator folder, my jar is created like this:

[image]

and I have into src folder \com\ and \java_cup\ and the jar seems not to work.
Do you have any ideea how could I put com and java_cup folders into the root of the jar (from command line)? like eclipse does?

Thanks!

Comment: in fact the problem is that it does not put the classes and the java files all together. How can I do that from command line?

Comment: Go into the bin directory, add the classes, then change into the src directory, update the jar with the java files, etc. not very elegant I admit

Comment: Or check the eclipse jdt docs if eclipse has a command line call to perform that...

Comment: yes, I can use ant... I just put all classes and java code all together and it works but as Stefan H. said is not so elegant. I will search a solution with ant...